# Using context and executor service (Android Wi-Fi)

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-wifi, runnable

I am trying to get the signal strengths of various Access Points in the vicinity.

My `scanWifi()` function is doing most of the processing for this in a separate class. As a result I have a need to use `Context` as a parameter for this function.

In the `WiFi class`:

```
public class Wifi {

    public void scanWifi(Context context, String APName, ArrayList<Integer> accessPointMeanRSSArrayList, ArrayList<Integer> accessPointRSSFrequencyArrayList) throws Exception {

        ArrayList<Integer> tempRSSArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        boolean AP_found = false;

        WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Currently I am implementing this as follows in my `Main Activity`:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    Runnable periodicTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Wifi wifiObject = new Wifi();
            // For each AP in the database, we will fill the AP's ArrayList with their corresponding RSS values
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : AccessPoints.entrySet()){
                int APNoToBeSent = 0;

                try {
                    wifiObject.scanWifi(getApplicationContext(), entry.getKey(), accessPointMeanRSSArrayList, accessPointRSSFrequencyArrayList);
                }

                catch(Exception e) {
                }

                ++APNoToBeSent;
            }


            System.out.println("Mean AP0 = " + accessPointMeanRSSArrayList.get(0));
            System.out.println("Frqcy AP0 = " + accessPointRSSFrequencyArrayList.get(0));
        }
    };

    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(periodicTask, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I am unsure whether I am using `getApplicationContext()` correctly here as I've read of people using `Singletons` and also heard that using `getApplicationContext()` is not the correct method nor are using `Singletons`.

All of this has me a little confused as to what the best practice is in this instance. Should I be passing Context to my `scanWifi()` function in a different manner?

Comment: Do I miss the singleton? Passing a Context is prone to leakage. So if the only reason you pass the context is getting the WifiManager, then maybe get it in the caller and pass it instead of the context.

Comment: You can pass the context from the MainActivity to Wifi.scanWifi method. There's no need to use the application context.

Comment: @ChuongPham As far as I see, there is even no need to pass a context at all. The function only needs the WifiManager.

Comment: @Fildor, yes we are just trying to get the WifiManager. Can you please clarify what you mean by getting it in the caller and passing it instead of context?

Comment: I mean instead of `scanWifi( Context context ...` you put `scanWifi( WiFiManager mgr ... ` I upvoted weston's answer for simplicity, though.

Comment: @Fildor thanks for your explanation. When you  implement it your way, why does the WifiManager not require context whereas weston's answer passes context via the constructor?

Comment: weston's Approach only uses the context in the constructor to get an instance of the WifiManager and keep that. After the ctor is done, the context is no longer needed. You could as well pass the WiFiManager to the constructor. It's just convenient to be able to pass `Activity.this`

Comment: @OsborneCox: Sorry, I just got back to the computer. Anyway, the second method I was going to suggest has already been answered by **weston** below. His answer is what you need.

Comment: Thanks ChuongPham, Fildor and Weston for all your assistance with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a singleton you are creating one every two seconds.

I'd pass the context to the constructor, not the method:

```
public class Wifi {

    private final WifiManager wifiManager;

    public Wifi(Context context){
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    }

    public void scanWifi(String APName, ArrayList<Integer> accessPointMeanRSSArrayList, ArrayList<Integer> accessPointRSSFrequencyArrayList) throws Exception {

        ArrayList<Integer> tempRSSArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        boolean AP_found = false;
```

Create from inside runnable like this:

```
Wifi wifiObject = new Wifi(Activity.this);
```

**Alternative:**

```
public class Wifi {

    private final WifiManager wifiManager;

    public Wifi(WifiManager wifiManager){
        this.wifiManager = wifiManager;
    }
```

Create like this:

```
 Wifi wifiObject = new Wifi((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE));
```

It's a matter or personal preference to an extent.

First option: `Context` is readily available in android. This method hides away the code you need to use to get to the wifi service making it simpler to remember how to use it.

The second option however has minimal dependencies (fewer `import` statements). If `context` was not so ubiquitous or I already had a reference to the wifi service ready to pass in I'd probably go for the second option. I'd also favour this option if there were multiple ways to get access to the `WifiManager`.